# How to log Apache CXF Soap Request and Soap Response using Log4j?

Tags: log4j, cxf

I am using the Apache CXF Framework.
Inside my client program, I need to log CXF SOAP Requests and SOAP Responses.
When I used

```java
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setAddress(host);
factory.setServiceClass(MyService.class);
factory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```

I got these SOAP Request and SOAP Responses in the console:

```
Nov 9, 2011 6:48:01 PM org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor$LoggingCallback onClose
INFO: Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 2
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns4:MYResponse
--------------------------------------
```

But my actual requirement is, instead of printing them to the server console, I need to have them inside the log file.

When I used log4j directly as shown

```java
log4j(factory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor()));
log4j(factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor()));
```

It is only printing `true` and `true` inside the log file.

Could anybody please let me know how to configure this?

Comment: The same problem was discussed here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592422/logging-request-response-with-apache-cxf-as-xml/17962979#17962979

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need to create a file named `org.apache.cxf.Logger` (that is: `org.apache.cxf` file with `Logger` extension) under `/META-INF/cxf/` with the following contents:

```
org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger
```

Reference: [Using Log4j Instead of java.util.logging](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html#DebuggingandLogging-UsingLog4jInsteadofjava.util.logging).

Also if you replace standard:

```xml
<cxf:bus>
  <cxf:features>
    <cxf:logging/>
  </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

with much more verbose:

```xml
<bean id="abstractLoggingInterceptor" abstract="true">
    <property name="prettyLogging" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="loggingInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor"/>
<bean id="loggingOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor"/>

<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
    <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```

Apache CXF will pretty print XML messages formatting them with proper indentation and line breaks. Very useful. More about it [here](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/05/enabling-load-balancing-and-failover-in.html).

Comment: Hi thomas , currently under META-INF folder , i have a file named MANIFEST.MF . Do you mean to add a cxf folder under META-INF ?? and please tell me how to create this file org.apache.cxf.Logger??

Comment: Yes, create `/cxf` folder in `/META-INF` and place a file named `org.apache.cxf` file with `Logger` extension there. Also see my updates.

Comment: please see the image http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=adouue&s=5     , i have created the folders

Comment: Just one staright question , you mean to create a folder struture as META-INF\cxf\org\apache\cxf\Logger , this is what you mean ??

Comment: The **file** must be named `org.apache.cxf` with `Logger` extension. As far as I can see you have created a file `\META-INF\cxf\org\apache\cxf\Logger.class` rather than `\META-INF\cxf\org.apache.cxf.Logger`. I have never said you need to create a directory structure of `\org\apache\cxf`. This is the file name (awkward, I must admit).

Comment: I dont know i should you this or not , but still , where can i find this file org.apache.cxf.Logger , because i am seeing files as org\apache\log4j

Comment: OK, have a look at [Using Log4j Instead of java.util.logging](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html#DebuggingandLogging-UsingLog4jInsteadofjava.util.logging), this is really a matter of creating a one-line file in your project...

Comment: Thanks for the link , it helped get started , i have downloaded Log4jLogger from cxf jar . After creating the directory structure and pasting the file , Do i need to configure anything inside log4j.properties file ??

Comment: If nothing appears now on the console then yes, you need to configure `log4j.properties` file. But this is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I have already configured log4j , Actually , my other log debug startements are coming , but not this . any idea ??

Comment: Make sure `org.apache.cxf` logger is set to `ALL` or `DEBUG`.

Comment: I do not have `org.apache.cxf.Logger` file anywhere. And having only `<cxf:bus><cxf:features><cxf:logging/></cxf:features></cxf:bus>` in my bean config prints messages with formatting (but I know that answer is 2 years old).

Comment: See for additional pretty-printing options: https://github.com/greenbird/xml-formatter-components/tree/master/cxf

Answer (score 20):

Another easy way is to set the logger like this- ensure that you do it before you load the cxf web service related classes. You can use it in some static blocks.

```java
YourClientConstructor() {

  LogUtils.setLoggerClass(org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger.class);

  URL wsdlURL = YOurURL;//

  //create the service
  YourService = new YourService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
  port = yourService.getServicePort(); 

  Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
  client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
  client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
}
```

Then the inbound and outbound messages will be printed to Log4j file instead of the console. Make sure your log4j is configured properly

Comment: I recommend to also enable pretty logging with: `AbstractLoggingInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true)`

Answer (score 14):

Simplest way to achieve pretty logging in Preethi Jain szenario:

```java
LoggingInInterceptor loggingInInterceptor = new LoggingInInterceptor();
loggingInInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true);
LoggingOutInterceptor loggingOutInterceptor = new LoggingOutInterceptor();
loggingOutInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true);
factory.getInInterceptors().add(loggingInInterceptor);
factory.getOutInterceptors().add(loggingOutInterceptor);
```

Comment: LoggingInInterceptor and LoggingOutInterceptor are deprecated: "use the logging module rt/features/logging instead"

Answer (score 5):

In your spring context configuring below would log the request and response soap messsage.

```
<bean id="loggingFeature" class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature">
    <property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
</bean>

<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <ref bean="loggingFeature" />
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

Setup log4j as normal. Then use this code:

```
    // LOGGING 
    LoggingOutInterceptor loi = new LoggingOutInterceptor(); 
    loi.setPrettyLogging(true); 
    LoggingInInterceptor lii = new LoggingInInterceptor(); 
    lii.setPrettyLogging(true); 

    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(isalesService); 
    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint(); 

    cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(loi); 
    cxfEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(lii);
```

Comment: @AI Grant, where to add this?

Answer (score 2):

Procedure for global setting of client/server logging of SOAP/REST requests/ responses with `log4j` logger.
This way you set up logging for the whole application without having to change the code, war, jar files, etc.

1. install file `cxf-rt-features-logging-X.Y.Z.jar` to your `CLASS_PATH`
2. create file (path for example: `/opt/cxf/cxf-logging.xml`):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
   <cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingFeature">
    <property name="prettyLogging" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>
    </beans>
   ```
3. set logging for `org.apache.cxf` (log4j 1.x) `log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=INFO,YOUR_APPENDER`
4. set these properties on java start-up

`java ... -Dcxf.config.file.url=file:///opt/cxf/cxf-logging.xml -Dorg.apache.cxf.Logger=org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true -Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true -Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true ...`

I don't know why, but it is necessary to set variables as well `com.sun.xml.*`

Answer (score 1):

When configuring `log4j.properties`, putting `org.apache.cxf` logging level to `INFO` is enough to see the plain SOAP messages:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=INFO
```

DEBUG is too verbose.

Comment: Setting org.apache to TRACE was first thing I tried and SOAP messages are not logged. Only thing what is loaded is something like `TRACE [http-8080-1] [org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker] Invoking method ...` but this is too late, because when parsing fails request is not logged at all...

Answer (score 1):

**cxf.xml**

```xml
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:ininterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
    </cxf:ininterceptors>
    <cxf:outinterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOutInterceptor" />
    </cxf:outinterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```

**org.apache.cxf.Logger**

```
org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger
```

Please check screenshot [here](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2012/07/configure-log4j-with-cxf)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```java
EndpointImpl impl = (EndpointImpl)Endpoint.publish(address, implementor);
    impl.getServer().getEndpoint().getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    impl.getServer().getEndpoint().getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```

Inside the `logback.xml` you need to put the interface name for webservice:

```xml
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator
        class="com.progressoft.ecc.integration.logging.ThreadNameDiscriminator">
        <key>threadName</key>
        <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator>
            <expression>logger.contains("InterfaceWebServiceSoap")</expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>NEUTRAL</OnMatch>
    </filter>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>TRACE</level>
    </filter>
    <sift>
        <appender name="FILE-${threadName}"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <File>${LOGGING_PATH}/${threadName}.log</File>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <FileNamePattern>${ARCHIVING_PATH}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.${threadName}%i.log.zip
                </FileNamePattern>
                <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
                <TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                    <MaxFileSize>50MB</MaxFileSize>
                </TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <Pattern>%date{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %5level | %-60([%logger{53}:%line]): %msg %ex{full} %n</Pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody wants to do this, using Play Framework (and using LogBack http://logback.qos.ch/), then you can configure the application-logger.xml with this line:

```
 <logger name="org.apache.cxf" level="DEBUG"/>
```

For me, it did the trick ;)

Comment: That would put at DEBUG every soap service log, if you have 3 and you want to enable log just for 1 of them this doesn't apply...

Comment: You're right. But for sure you will  log CXF SOAP Requests and SOAP Responses as the question asks.

Answer (score 1):

**Old configuration options will not work for those who use Apache CXF version 3.1 or later**. Check [here](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/message-logging.html). In my case, I used apache cxf 3.4.2 in spring boot (version 2.4.2) project.

To print logging properly, you need to add feature in your `Bus` object (in my case, it was `SpringBus`) like following -

1. Create `LoggingFeature` -

```
LoggingFeature loggingFeature = new LoggingFeature();
loggingFeature.setPrettyLogging(true);
```

2. Create/autowire Bus object, then set feature to bus

```
bus.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(loggingFeature));
```

In case if you need to check how will create bus in spring boot project, please check [here](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/springboot.html).