# Logging CXF rest service

Tags: java, apache, web-services, cxf, slf4j

I am trying to log my rest service as below in cxf.xml,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

    <jaxrs:server id="base" address="/Restful">

    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
         <ref bean="Service" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

    <jaxrs:features>
         <cxf:logging />
    </jaxrs:features>

    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="Service" class="com.xxx.yyy.services.ServiceImpl" />

    </beans>
```

In console it prints only Outbound message as below,

```
Nov 27, 2015 3:36:47 PM org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor
    INFO: Outbound Message
    ---------------------------
    ID: 1
    Response-Code: 200
    Content-Type: text/plain
    Headers: {Content-Type=[text/plain], Date=[Fri, 27 Nov 2015 10:06:47 GMT]}
    Payload: your request has been proceed..
    --------------------------------------
```

**Question,**

It would be appreciated if you could let me know how to enable Inbound message as well?

**Additional details,**

CXF 3.1.4
Java 7

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the stackoverflow link [How to log Apache CXF Soap Request and Soap Response using Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065737/how-to-log-apache-cxf-soap-request-and-soap-response-using-log4j)

Also, Apache CFX web site [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/configuration.html) section "Enabling message logging using plain Spring bean elements"

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response,
1. The stackoverflow link provided is regarding SOAP service.
2. I have referred the Apache CXF link already , However when i tried it i got the below exception while using bus-->

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf':
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cxf.config0' while setting bean property 'busConfig'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No bean named 'cxf.config0' is defined

Answer (score 0):

You can set configuration like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">


<bean id="abstractLoggingInterceptor" abstract="true">
    <property name="prettyLogging" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="loggingInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor"/>
<bean id="loggingOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor"/>



    <jaxrs:server id="base" address="/Restful">

    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
         <ref bean="Service" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

    <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
       <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
    </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
    <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
       <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
    </jaxrs:outInterceptors>
    <jaxrs:outFaultInterceptors>
       <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
    </jaxrs:outFaultInterceptors>
    <jaxrs:inFaultInterceptors>
       <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
    </jaxrs:inFaultInterceptors>

    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="Service" class="com.xxx.yyy.services.ServiceImpl" />

    </beans>
```