# Apache cxf file logging

Tags: java, spring, logging, jboss, cxf

I've configured `CXF` and now I want to use logging and configure it from xml without extra code. For this purpose, I've added this xml configuration to my `appContext`:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" id="logInInterceptor" />
    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" id="logOutInterceptor" />
    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>

    </cxf:bus>

    <jaxws:endpoint id="myServiceBean" implementor="com.mysite.webservice.myWSDLBean_Client" address="/mySearch">
    </jaxws:endpoint>
```

but it doesn't log anything during call, though when there is server deployment, I see that `logInInterceptor` and `logOutInterceptor` are mapped. What am I doing wrong?

And is there any way to configure writing logs to an external file (not to console) ?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8065874/5934435

Comment: @Sampada I've added as it was said - new logging file with the mentioned property, then added missing spring configuration properties, but there was no miracle =( I didn't see anything even in console

Comment: @Frank I use 2.5 version

Comment: @Frank yes, this file is correctly in `src/main/resources` folder. BTW, you mentioned difference between configuration of 2.5 and 3.1+ versions. Can you describe them?

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes and it should work for you -

1. Add fault interceptors to your `<cxf:bus>`:

   ```
   <cxf:bus>
       .
       .
       .
       <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
           <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
       </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
       <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
           <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
       </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
   </cxf:bus>`
   ```
2. Add a file `org.apache.cxf.Logger` in your `/META-INF/cxf` with contents:

   ```
   org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Slf4jLogger
   ```
3. In JBoss's `standalone.xml`, add the following property after `<extensions>`:

   ```
    <system-properties>
       <property name="org.apache.cxf.logging.enabled" value="true"/>
    </system-properties>`
   ```