# CXF log SOAP output

Tags: soap, cxf

I am having trouble logging an outgoing SOAP message from the server.  The handleMessage method does not overwrite the message content as expected.  How would I store the outgoing SOAP to the message?

```
public class OutgoingSoapInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OutgoingSoapInterceptor.class.getName());

    public OutgoingSoapInterceptor ()
    {
        super(Phase.PRE_STREAM);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        logger.debug("outbound soap handleMessage");

        OutputStream os = message.getContent ( OutputStream.class );
        CacheAndWriteOutputStream cwos = new CacheAndWriteOutputStream ( os);
        message.setContent ( OutputStream.class, cwos );

        cwos.registerCallback ( new LoggingOutCallBack ( ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way to log the SOAP messages using CXF `LoggingInInterceptor` and `LoggingOutInterceptor`

```
  LogUtils.setLoggerClass(org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger.class);

  yourService = new YourService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
  port = yourService.getServicePort(); 

  Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
  client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
  client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```

Or configuring interceptors  in `<cxf:bus>` with spring

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/core 
     http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging />
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>  

    <jaxws:endpoint ... />        
</beans>
```

See more examples in [How to log Apache CXF Soap Request and Soap Response using Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065737/how-to-log-apache-cxf-soap-request-and-soap-response-using-log4j)

Comment: This put me on the right path.  In the process I ran across this system property:  https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Advanced+User+Guide#AdvancedUserGuide-Systemproperty

Comment: I did not know the property. I do not know if it is standard of cxf or own jboss

Comment: The log output gets truncated. How can we log the complete xml in/out message regardless of message size ?

Comment: Some of the API is now deprecated. Should be `org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Slf4jLogger.class`now and `org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingOutInterceptor` from `org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-features-logging`.