# Handling Pre/Post Processing of CXF Requests

Tags: java, filter, jax-rs, cxf, interceptor

We started auditing our clients requests on the server by its CRUD operation.

Instead of calling the audit class to log the request, we want to use a CXF Filter to pre-process & post-process each request. What do I mean?

We want to audit every update request (which contains a JSON) with its old value (before the change, a GET operation to the DB), but log it into the logger only **after** the request completed successfully.

We are already using this method for changing the response body when an exception is thrown (by using a jaxsrs:providers tag and an ExceptionMapper implementation), but I can't understand how to use it for pre/post processing of requests.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**:

Well I kinda understood what I need to do to make a CXF Interceptor:

- Create a class extending `AbstractPhaseInterceptor`
- In your class constructor call `super(Phase.[the-needed-pahse])` to decide when will your interceptor run ([here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html) is a list of all incoming/outgoing phases)
- Override `handleMessage` as it is the inherited method, here you'll write your logic
- Add the interceptor to the `web.xml` file of your project

For example:

```
public void handleMessage(Message request) throws Fault {       
    try {
        InputStream is = request.getContent(InputStream.class);
        String reqBodyAsString = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8");
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);       
        // Do the logic
        is = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toInputStream(reqBodyAsString, "UTF-8");
        request.setContent(InputStream.class, is);
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
    } 
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the `web.xml` file:

```
<jaxrs:server id="[id]" address="[URL]">
    <jaxrs:inInterceptors><!-- because we want it to run BEFORE the request logic -->
        <ref bean="[interceptor-id]" />
    </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
</jaxrs:server>

<bean id="[interceptor-id]" class="[package-path.interceptor-class-name]"/>
```

You can see that after reading the content I write it back again into the request. That is because I get an exception saying my body is `null`.

And this is where I'm stuck, I have an interceptor but after reading the request-body, it seems that the logic can't be continued.

Comment: Have you thought about doing this right before you insert/update to the database (instead of doing it at HTTP interceptor) transactionally? Are you using any ORM frameworks ? If you are using hibernate, there are ways to tap into the events and use that to create Audit entries. Example: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/

Comment: @random_dude We're not using a standard DB, and we don't want to audit each and every operation only specific operations sent from a specific URL. Before the write-operation we don't have all the data we want to log about the transaction, we need to make it a little bit higher in the chain

Comment: Why do you close  the input stream  right after setting it? 

        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);'

Comment: @TMtech Because I don't really need it anymore, I checked and it doesn't have any change on the extracted String. BTW the set operation succeeds, I tried to extract it again after the setContent() and it's there, so I really don't know why I get a null on the request-logic (after the interceptor finishes)

Comment: @Lior What do you mean by _I don't need it any more_? That input stream is the content of the HTTP request body. If you close input stream in a filter or an interceptor, request body will not be passed to resource methods.  Remove that line (`org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);`) and retry. If it did not solve the problem, update the question with the error message(stack trace or something)

Answer (score 0):

You are consuming the request stream. You need to cache it before logging, and set a new stream in CXF message

```
public void handleMessage(Message message) {
      //Get the message body into payload[] and set a new non-consumed  inputStream into Message
      InputStream in = message.getContent(InputStream.class);
      byte payload[] = IOUtils.readBytesFromStream(in); //log this
      ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(payload);
    message.setContent(InputStream.class, bin);
 }
```

Close streams is not needed. Note also you can use CXF default logging interceptors https://stackoverflow.com/a/37820362/6371459