# how to change wsse:KeyIdentifier to wsse:Reference with CXF

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I'm using **CXF** 3.1.5, trying to send a **request** to a **STS** server, the **STS** server has a **policy**, the related part is as following

```
<wsp:Policy>
    <sp:RequireThumbprintReference />
    <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
</wsp:Policy>
```

so in the **request** **CXF** sends to the **STS** server, the **signature key** looks like that:

```
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="...">
    <wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="..."ValueType="...#ThumbprintSHA1">...</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
```

**but** I want to change the **SecurityTokenReference** into that

```
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    <wsse:Reference URI="..." ValueType="...#**X509v3**"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
```

it refers to the **BinarySecurityToken** which is a **X.509 Certificate**

So what should I do? I found something about **PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor** and **PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor**, but don't known how they works.

Thanks a lots!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pedrofb, thanks a lot for your help. unfortunately, I still got two BinarySecurityToken Elements and I couldn't use an alternative policy file.

but I found a solution here:[How to get incoming & outgoing soap xml in a simple way using Apache CXF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038313/how-to-get-incoming-outgoing-soap-xml-in-a-simple-way-using-apache-cxf)

It provides a solution for me to edit the soap envelop right before CXF sends it out. It's not very good, but it's the best solution I got.

Answer (score 1):

You need a certificate issued by a CA accepted by your server to sign the SOAP request. You can use CXF with `WSS4JOutInterceptor`

This is the configuration to use WSS4J with CXF. Omit the part of creating the keystore

Set [WSS4J properties](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/config.html) (adjust to your policy)

```
outProps.put("action", "Signature");
outProps.put("user", certificateAlias);
outProps.put("passwordType", "PasswordText");
outProps.put("signaturePropFile", propertiesFile);
outProps.put("signatureKeyIdentifier","DirectReference");
outProps.put("passwordCallbackRef",clientPasswordCallback);
```

`propertiesFile` contains the path to a properties file where is configured the path to the keystore

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=changeit
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file=keystore.jks
```

`ClientPasswordCallback` performs a callback from wss4j to get the password of the certificate

```
public class ClientPasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {
   String password = ...; //Configure the password

   public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) {
     for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
        WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[i];
        pc.setPassword(password);
      }
   }
}
```

Configure the CXF client using the WebService port

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();
WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

//Include LoggingOutInterceptor to log the soap message
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```

And finally call your service

```
port.myService();
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detail reply! I implemented your solution, right now, I got another problem. in the request, some elements in soap header are duplicated, like wsse:BinarySecurityToken, <wsu:Timestamp and ds:Signature. I think WSS4JOutInterceptor added those elements but didn't remove the original elements. what should I do about that?

Comment: Why you have those elements at header? Remove the original header before `WSS4JOutInterceptor` is executed and let this interceptor to configure the SOAP header

Comment: It's added by ws-policy, I think when CXF resolve the policy, those elements are added automatically. I don't know how to intercept the process. basically that's the problem. the problem is when CXF adds the element wsse:SecurityTokenReference according to the policy, it uses wsse:KeyIdentifier under it, but I want it to use wsse:Reference. if it's possible to remove something first, I think it's okay too.

Comment: and I cannot change the policy.

Comment: Seems CXF PolicyOutInterceptor is adding the policy before yours. I think it can disabled using `<p:engine enabled="true" ignoreUnknownAssertions="true"/>` See http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wspconfiguration.html. If it does not works the alternative is configure an alternative policy file with `<jaxws:features><p:policies><wsp:PolicyReference` See http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-to-define-policies.html and set the extra params WS-Security params needed (keystore and passwords). In this page are documented the parameters http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html

Comment: the first solution doesn't work, I'll try to use the second one. and another problem, the timestamp element is not signed, so how to sign it? I wrote properties.put("action", "Signature Timestamp") but doesn't work.

Comment: You need to change the order of actions `properties.put("action", "Timestamp Signature");` and include the nodes to sign `properties.put("signatureParts", "{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp;{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body");` See https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/using.html