# Retrieve WS request in CXF Web service

Tags: apache, web-services, osgi, cxf

I got a CXF OSGi Web service (based on the example demo in servicemix: https://github.com/apache/servicemix/tree/master/examples/cxf/cxf-jaxws-blueprint)

The Web service works fine and i call all the available implemented methods of the service.

My question is how can i retrieve the request inside a WS method and parse in a string XML format.

I have found that this is possible inside interceptors for logging, but i want also to the WS-Request inside my methods.

Comment: If you want the plain xml then why use jax ws? What do yo need the xml for?

Comment: i want the actual payload of the request as seen in my servicemix logs. To the question "What for do i need it" . I store the payload in my database for further future processing.

Comment: I see here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038313/how-to-get-incoming-outgoing-soap-xml-in-a-simple-way-using-apache-cxf ) some ways to get the message from an interceptor as mentioned above , but i need that payload in me WS methods.

Comment: One of the main goal of jax-ws and jaxb is to translate the payload into a tree of java Object. Getting the payload "as string" at the WebService level is simply a nonsense.
If you really want the payload as string, you should not work at WebService level but at HTTP level.

Comment: We are missing the point. I do not mind if it is nonsense or not. My question is if it is possible something like that. As i said on my previous comment, i have an implementation that at some points stores the payload as a string in the database.  Thats why the LoegEventSender or interceptors do not qualify my needs

Answer (score 1):

For storing the request in the database I suggest to extend the [new CXF message logging](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/message-logging.html).

You can implement a custom [LogEventSender](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/rt/features/logging/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/ext/logging/event/LogEventSender.java) that writes into the database.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal but this does not answer the actual question. How or if i can get inside my webmethod the request payload.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirement where I need to save data into DB once method is invoked. I had used `ThreadLocal` with `LoggingInInterceptor` and `LoggingOutInterceptor`. For example in LoggingInInterceptor I used to set the message into ThreadContext and in webservice method get the message using `LoggingContext.getMessage()` and in LoggingOutInterceptor I used to removed the message(**NOTE: Need to be careful here you need to explictly remove the message from thread context else you will end up with memory leak, and also incase of client side code interceptors get reversed.**

```
public class LoggingContext {

    private static ThreadLocal<String> message;

    public static Optional<String> getMessage() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(message.get());
    }

    public static void setMessage(final String message) {
        LoggingContext.message = new ThreadLocal<>();
        LoggingContext.message.set(message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to this question but i achieved to do my task by using JAXB in the end and do some manipulations there.