# Customize Apache CXF Intercepter

Tags: java, cxf, interceptor

With the following link [Logging request/response with Apache CXF as XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592422/logging-request-response-with-apache-cxf-as-xml), I can log my Webservice SOAP Request to server console log file, my implementation likes this:

```
ServerFactoryBean svrFactory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
svrFactory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor(newPrintWriter(System.err)));
svrFactory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor(new PrintWriter(System.err)));
```

But now I want to check a param "MESSAGE_ID" in the SOAP request to save the SOAP request to the separated file MESSAGE_ID.xml.

Is there any way to do in the Interceptor implementation ?

Comment: Create your own interceptor class that extends ``AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>``. In the method ``handleMessage`` you have access to the soap message, where you can access the payload.

Comment: It works. thank @f1sh