# Change log level of generated CXF server with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, cxf, slf4j

I have generated a CXF server using [wsdl2java](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) and I'm facing issues with the resulting web service for external reasons. In order to properly debug it, I'd like to change the log level of this CXF server from default to something **very** verbose (DEBUG?).

I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065737/how-to-log-apache-cxf-soap-request-and-soap-response-using-log4j) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592422/logging-request-response-with-apache-cxf-as-xml/17962979#17962979), but I don't get it and it seems like the solutions are not adapted to my code. I have no idea where to put the pieces of code that are given and I didn't configure my Spring application with XML files.

Here is the generated `ValidationPort_BasicHttpBindingValidation_Server` by wsdl2java:

```java
// I have edited this WS a little to run it with spring instead of a main.
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ValidationPort_BasicHttpBindingValidation_Server {
    public final static String ADDRESS = "http://localhost/PRE-VAROTH/Validation/V1";

    protected ValidationPort_BasicHttpBindingValidation_Server() {
        log.info("Starting Server");
        Endpoint.publish(ADDRESS, new BasicHttpBinding_ValidationImpl());
    }
}
```

My logging framework is Slf4j and I'd like the log to be passed to that framework. I think I can make this part work but when I launch my server and try a sample SOAP request I don't see anything on the log or the console...

Here is my Spring Boot entry point:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Value("${server.http.port}")
    private int serverPortHttp;

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private int serverPortHttps;

    private Connector createHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setPort(serverPortHttp);
        connector.setRedirectPort(serverPortHttps);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

How am I supposed to change properly the logging level of this CXF server?

Comment: Have you redirected the java.util.logging to slf4j as described here? http://cxf.apache.org/docs/general-cxf-logging.html

Comment: @DennisKieselhorst thanks for the suggestion, yes I did that but the logging level was not right and changing log level via spring boot as Boris suggested did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot configures logging to log to the console at INFO level. To set the logging level to **DEBUG**, you should create properties in *application.properties* that are prefixed with *logging.level*:

```
logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

More info on Spring Boot logging can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-logging).

Comment: Changing Spring Boot logging level will change the logging level of CXF server I assume? Why didn't I think of that earlier...

Comment: So I added `logging.level.root: debug` to my application.yml (which is the equivalent) but it seems like it's somewhat totally ignored. I'm looking deeper into it and will upvote/accept as soon as I get what's going on.